# Are Muslim jins Sunni or Shia? (If there are Muslim jins)

Tags: shia-sunni, jinn, sects

In case of being the Muslim jins, are they divided in Sunni and Shia like Muslims?

*Note: I am looking for authentic ahadith.*

Comment: -1 there is no `sunni` or `shia` at the time of prophet.

Comment: Dear suhail, you say there was no sunni or shia at the time of the prophet? So, if you say it, then why at the moment there are Shia and Sunni people? (so according to your speech, there was not Sunni and Shia at the time of the prophet?!

Comment: There are all kinds of aqeedah among the jinns, just as there are among humans. So there are Muslims, Christians, Buddhists, Hindus, and so on among them. So I guess even the various sects of Islam must be reflected among them.

Comment: @Najeeb, yeah, I agree with you, it is a rational answer, Since as far as I know, jins have option like us, accordingly they could have different religion.

Comment: This question might sound bizarre, but I have personally heard about jinns who had pleaded allegiance to Prophet's Ahlulbayt and this does find reference in Shiite hadith sources. That might explain the relevance of the question to Islam.

Comment: @Salamislam , bro if you speak Arabic i can send u a link to a book, it explains a lot about jinn, you will love this book as it will clarify so much about the word of jinn!!

Comment: Muslims are divided into Sunni and Shia's in men, by the effect of Shaitan, and hence disparities. But even in Jinns, there would be disparities because of Shaitan who knows but need not be in the names of Sunni and Shia.

Comment: Yeah, I agree you somewhat, but I assume it could be feasible as a probable issue that there is both Shia and Sunni Jinn, couldn't it? Since as u mentioned, Shaitan can be cause disunion or division of different sects...  And God knows best.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to know, what is the use of asking such a question? Even if you found out the answer what will you do with it?

Also the Question You ask, has a problem with it.

You are asking for Ahadith to prove if Jin are Shia or Sunni. But you must remember, in the time of Prophet there was no sect known as Shia and Sunni... So how can there be hadith from Prophet (PBUH) about Shia, Sunni????

It was many years after, that people started studying deeply into Islamic Studies that sects started to emerge.

Right now we have 5 main madhabs of Islam. 4 Sunni (Hanafi, Maliki, Sha'fi, Hanbali) and 1 Shia (Ja'fri)

Interestingly all the imams; Imam Abu Hanifa, Imam Malik, Imam Sha'fi, Imam Ahmed ibn Hanbal were the students of Imam Jafar as Sadiq. (Who is the great grandson of the Prophet)..

(Note: This question cannot be answered because it is problematic.)

Comment: Shia is Not from the Ja'fri Madhab do a deep study otherwise they will also be considered as sunni and considered among the 5th madhab why all others scholars are considered as sunni. Imam jafar never gone against the companion of prophets decisions.

Comment: @Ali, you said: "if you found out the answer what will you do with it?!"  Oh, If you think like that, then I reckon you should say it for most questions of this site that "if you found out the answer what will you do with it?!" ,

Comment: @Ali, you likewise said that" .. how can be hadith from the Prophet(PBUH) about Shia, Sunni????"  So, I Did not say if there is any hadith from the prophet, I inquired is there any authentic ahadith? (e.g. from Imams ..).  anyhow God bless you (since anyway it is very nice of you that paid attention to my question)

Comment: @Salamislam .. Salaam Dear Brother ! Oh I see where you were coming from. Yes Hadith from the Imam alhehimusalaam... no dear brother, I do not know of any such. Forgive me if I sounded arrogant or disrespectful... I did not have such an intention.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are both sunnis and shias among them just like there exist different sects among the humans.

> #### وأنا منا الصالحون ومنا دون ذلك كنا طرائق قددا
>
> And among us are the righteous, and among us are [others] not so; we were [of] divided ways.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 72:11](https://quran.com/72/11?translations=20)</sup>

> وقال الحسن والسدي : الجن أمثالكم فمنهم قدرية ومرجئة ورافضة
>
> Al-Hassan and As-Suddi said: The Jinn are like you, there are among them Qadariyah, Murji’ah and Shi'as.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura72-aya11.html)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

A very good question but no one has given you precise answer. Well your answer can be given by a Muslim Jinn only and here it is. Come out of the books written by humans and follow the book of Allah and love Ahl ul Bait as these are the only two things Prophet Muhammad S.A.W.W left for us. The Book is with them and they are with the book. Without these two together you are nothing.

"The human does not even know that there were so many Messengers who were from the race of Djinns before creation of mankind and they all love Prophet Muhammad S.A.W.W. and his People of the house (Ahl ul Bait A.S) since the beginning even when they were in their original form (Noor) in heavens and were not sent in the form of humans on Earth. We saw with our own eyes what all the khaaki (the clay creature) did with them and their bloodline. Even we the Djinns and you the clay creature both send Darood to Prophet Muhammad and His bloodline. But in reality you preferred clay over Noor and their servants to be your leaders. We are the lovers of Prophet Muhammad being Syed ul Anbia. We are the servants of Fatima tuz Zahra the Queen of ladies of the heaven Syeda tun Nisa. And we are servants of Ayma Hassnain A.S the Princes of Martyrs and Youngsters of heaven. Rest is all clay. But that clay is superior to Noor for you. Now you will understand that all muslim Djinns belong to which Fiqah unlike you clay creature."

Well as per this statement if an uneducated person asks how come there were Messengers among Jinns then you may ask them to read Verse 130 of Al Anaam.

“O company of jinn and mankind, did there not come to you messengers from among you, relating to you My verses and warning you of the meeting of this Day of yours?”

JazaakAllah.